# Export datastore values using bulkloader with mapping tables (GAE - Google app engine)

Tags: google-app-engine, bulkloader

I have two tables with relationship as follows, May i know how to exports (csv file), child table with parentid using bulkloader.

Table 1 : Parent

```
     @PersistenceCapable
     public class Parent{
     @PrimaryKey
     @Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
     private Long parentId;
     @Persistent
     private String name;
     @Persistent
     private Child child;
```

Table 2 : Child

```
   public class Child implements StoreCallback {
    @PrimaryKey
    @Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
    private Key childid;
    @Persistent
    private String name;
```